# How to return to the beginning of the console in printing in C++?

Tags: c++

if I have this code :

```
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int count = 0;

    while (true) {
        cout << "here: " << count++ << " again\r";  
    }

    return 0;
}
```

After it finishes, it will go back to the beginning of the line with carriage return.

Now assume I have more than one line like so :

```
    using namespace std;

int main() {

    int count = 0;
    int count2 = 3;
    int count3 = 4;
    

    while (true) {
        cout << "here: " << count++ << " again\r";
        cout << "here: " << count2++ << " again\r";
        cout << "here: " << count3++ << " again\r";
        cout << "here: " << count-- << " again\r";
    }
    

    return 0;
}
```

It's not working. I want to keep all lines, and when one of them finishes it returns at the beginning, but what I get is only one line in the console

Comment: C++ has no idea what a console is.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly but if you want each output on a separate line, replace \r with \n: cout << "here: " << count++ << " again\n";
OR  cout << "here: " << count++ << " again" << endl;

Comment: Please show the output you have in contrast to the one you want. Change-by-change if necessary.

Comment: @StureS I don't want new lines, I only want 4 lines. If I add \n then i will keep adding new lines down the page

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Positioning of text in a terminal is outside the scope of the C++ standard.

You can use portable [ncurses library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ncurses) for positioning of text on terminal/console.

Comment: Or use (on some OSes) [GNU readline](https://www.gnu.org/software/readline/) and perhaps provide autocompletion ...